# Dereferencing NULL pointer - Visual Studio

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

While using my code in Visual Studio, I got a warning of dereferencing NULL pointer at  `p[i] = (int)i;`. Anybody knows how can I avoid this warning?

```
#define ARRAY_LEN   5

int main(void)
{
    int* p;
    p = (int*)malloc(ARRAY_LEN * sizeof(int));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++)
    {
        p[i] = (int)i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it wants you to check the result of the `malloc` call before using `p`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The warning disappeared after adding a condition of exit(0) if(p == NULL).

Comment: Validate EVERY input and validate EVERY allocation -- life will be good...

Comment: Also a good read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole he has to  as he compiles as C++ code.

Comment: @0___________ Question is tagged C (not C++) and the code looks OK as C.